# How to unit test android.graphics.Bitmap and BitmapFactory?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, android-permissions, android-bitmap

I am working on an Imaging application.
I want to implement unit testing for Bitmap related functions.
I also need to see the output Bitmap.

I tried two options :

1. run the test in `test/java` so I can dump the output image to a file on my Mac and open it manually. But I got an `android.graphics.BitmapFactory not mocked`.
2. run the test in `androidTest/java` so BitmapFactory is fully implemented but:

   - I got `access denied` when trying to pull the file using `adb pull` using `mockContext.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`
   - I cannot write to an external directory because I cannot grant write access without and Activity using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` (EDIT : I was wrong you can grant READ and WRITE storage using adb utility)
   - If I make it work, I don't know how to hook to the gradle task to automate the pull command / or to grand write access at runtime.

So how to test Bitmap related code ? I am out of options !

Comment: The Unit Test application has the same privileges as the app that it's testing.  It should be possible for the unit test to take the photo from the private storage and move it to public storage.  It would even be possible to transfer it to a file server.

Answer (score 1):

What I finally did :

1. Create two Gradle Tasks that I can manually invoke before and after test.

   - the imagingBeforeTest is granting permission to access storage and cleaning directories
   - the imagingAfterTest is pulling the content of the directory on the device to the local build directory so you can explore it afterward.
2. Create a constant pointing to the same directory I defined in the Gradle tasks.

Java constant :

```
public static final File ANDROID_TEST_DIR = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "mypackage");
```

Gradle file :

```
def androidPlugin = project.plugins.findPlugin("android")
def adb = androidPlugin.sdkHandler.sdkInfo?.adb
def mypackageDir = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/mypackage'

//Grant necessary permissions and create storage dir
task imagingBeforeTest(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'pm', 'grant', 'fr.mycompany.mypackage', 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'pm', 'grant', 'fr.mycompany.mypackage', 'android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'rm', '-r', "$mypackageDir"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'mkdir', "$mypackageDir"
}

//Pull content of storage dir to the local build directory
task imagingAfterTest(type: Exec) {
    // Alias is /storage/self/primary/Download/mypackage
    File testDir = new File(rootProject.buildDir.absoluteFile, "/pulledTest")
    testDir.mkdir()
    commandLine "$adb", 'pull', "$mypackageDir", testDir.getAbsolutePath()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For bitmap related app main thing need to manage that is memory consumption of device.

So you need to manage bitmap properly with some caching mechanism.

For testing you can use Monitors service with Memory section in Android studio.

Comment: I don't understand you answer

Comment: You want to test your bitmap implementation with device right ?

Comment: No I want to test complex operation involving android.graphics.Bitmap